# PHP session clear unexpectedly in server

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm developing a project in ZendFramework 3. The session expires unexpectedly in production server. It expire unexpectedly when it sit idle for some time, very low say 10 minutes. It was not happening in my local development machine. I'm getting same `session_id()` before and after session expire. So it look something happening in server. Following are the server & zend configurations. Its default values and nothing altered by me.

Session Settings in INI File

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.gc_divisor = 100
session.save_path = 
session.use_only_cookies = On
session.gc_probability = 1
```

Zend Framework 3 Values

```
session_cookie_expire = 180 Minutes

session_get_cookie_params = [lifetime] => 3600
                [path] => /
                [domain] => 
                [secure] => 
                [httponly] =>
```

Session Details. These values are same before and after expiry.

```
session_id() : c12345666ae7abcd7894dd1234567eeded
session_name() : PHPSESSID
```

Comment: I'm guessing your dev and prod environments are not 1 on 1 clones (e.g. with Docker or Vagrant). Have you checked the `php.ini` config on the server? And the Apache's or nginx config for PHP? Mind that you might have multiple instances of PHP on your server, so make sure to check command-line `php phpinfo()` and also add `<?php phpinfo(); exit;` as the first line in the `public/index.php` file. Run and compare the results of both. Update results in question. Also compare the results of previous with your dev environment, update those results to question as well. (Please post just differences).

Comment: It was solved by setting session.save_path = "/path". I was losing session whenever the apache restarts, the IT team were restarting it frequently for some fixes.